# Proving $(1+\frac 1n)^{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n({\frac 1{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac rn))}$ using the binomial theorem

Tags: summation, products, binomial-theorem

> $$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left\{\frac 1{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac rn\right)\right\}$$

this exercise is taken from Apostol's Calculus I (page 45) and it's supposed to be proved by using the binomial theorem. I can only carry out the expression on the left this way:

$$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}1^k\left(\frac 1n\right)^{n-k}=1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k}\frac 1{n^{n-k}}$$

I have no clue on how to proceed.. any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can continue from there:
$$\begin{align}{n \choose k}\frac 1{n^{n-k}}&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!n^{n-k}}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!n^{n-k}}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}(n-r)\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-r}{n}\end{align}$$

and you can make the final step!.
But for the indexes for the sum in binomial theorem you might write:
$$(1+\frac 1n)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}1^k(\frac 1n)^{n-k}=1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k}\frac 1{n^{n-k}}$$
(because as you know ${n \choose 0}=1$ and what I wrote in the product above is not be true id $k=0$ because in this case we will have $\prod_{r=1}^{0-1}$ which does not have a sense)

Comment: thanks a lot @elaqqad , I started studying summation and product notation only recently, and got confused quite a lot..

Comment: still, I don't get why you put the $n^{n-k}$ in the product notation, and why the result from the book has a $\sum_{k=1}^n$ instead of the $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}$ I found. did the author shift the dummy index? thanks for your patience.

Comment: I added some tips to the answer!

Comment: I managed to understand it all by developing $(1+\frac 1n)^n$ as $\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(\frac 1n)^k1^{n-k}=1+\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}\frac 1{n^k}$, simplifying the steps a little bit. thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This proves the equality for a fixed $n>0$. But what if we want to show that the equality holds for any $n>0$ as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606147/use-the-binomial-theorem-to-prove-that-for-n-a-positive-integer-the-following ?

Comment: @utobi this proves the equality for __any fixed $n >0$__ which is _equivalent_ to the fact that the __equality holds for any $n>0$__ . The two statements mean the same thing there is no différence between them.