# For all $n >0$, $ \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n\bigl[ \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{r}{n}) \bigr]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am working through some problems on induction and I have been stuck on this one for a while. If anyone has any hints. I can show it is true for the $n=1$ and $n=2$ case but I am having difficulty on the induction step.
This is what I have so far,

$ (1+\frac{1}{n} )^n      =  1+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n[ \frac{1}{k!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{r}{n})  ]$

**$n =1 $ case**

$ (1+\frac{1}{1} )^1      = 1+  \sum\limits_{k=1}^1[ \frac{1}{k!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{r}{1})  ]$

$ 2    =  1+  \frac{1}{1!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{0}(1-\frac{r}{1})  ]= 1+(1-\frac{0}{1})=1+1=2$

So, 2=2. True

**$n=2$ case**

$ (1+\frac{1}{2} )^2      = 1+  \sum\limits_{k=1}^2[ \frac{1}{k!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{r}{2})  ]$

$ (1+\frac{1}{2} )^2      = 1+ [ \frac{1}{1!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{0}(1-\frac{r}{2})  ]+\frac{1}{2!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{1}(1-\frac{r}{2})  ]$

$ (1+\frac{1}{2} )^2      = 1+ [ \frac{1}{1!}  (1-\frac{0}{2})  ]+[\frac{1}{2!}   (1-\frac{1}{2})  ]$

$ (1+\frac{1}{2} )^2      = 1+ [ \frac{1}{1!}  (1)  ]+[\frac{1}{2!}   (\frac{1}{2})  ]$

$ (1+\frac{1}{2} )^2      = 1+ 1+  \frac{1}{4}  ]$

And finally, $\frac{9}{4} = \frac{9}{4}$

So the n=2 step is also true.

**Induction Step**

Show that the $(n+1)^{th}$ case is true when the $n^{th}$ case is true.

Now, I assume the $n^{th}$ case is true. So,

$ (1+\frac{1}{n} )^n      =  1+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n[ \frac{1}{k!}    \prod\limits_{r=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{r}{n})  ]$

then I multiply both sides by $ (1+\frac{1}{n} )^{n+1} $, but I haven't gotten far from there. Any hints would be great!

Comment: The simple way to do this appears to be the binomial theorem.

Comment: See here (from this site) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222412/proving-left1-frac-1n-rightn-1-sum-k-1n-frac-1k-prod-r-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the following development is not an induction proof, I thought it would be instructive to present a direct proof of the equality of interest.  To that end, we have from the binomial theorem

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

s(n+1)
Hints:
1.(1 + 1/n+1)^n+1 = (1 + 1/n)^n(1+ 1/n)...

2.Split up the sums

3.**Use the binomial Theorem**

Comment: Or just read this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222412/proving-left1-frac-1n-rightn-1-sum-k-1n-frac-1k-prod-r-0?lq=1