# Use the binomial theorem to prove that for $n$ a positive integer the following holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning, binomial-theorem

\begin{equation}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right\}\,.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

**Proof**.

By the binomial theorem

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n  {{n}\choose{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}.$$ Hence, to prove $(1)$, we must prove that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n  {{n}\choose{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right\}\,,\tag{2}
$$

for all positive integers $n$.

At present I can't find any reasonable quantity that if added on both sides leads to equality for $n+1$, *i.e.* the quantity that completes the proof. Any hint is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
A similar question has been asked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222412/proving-left1-frac-1n-rightn-1-sum-k-1n-frac-1k-prod-r-0?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599025/for-all-n-0-left1-frac1n-rightn-1-sum-k-1n-bigl-frac1?noredirect=1&lq=1) posts. What I'd like to do is to prove that (1) (or (2)) holds for **any** integer $n>0$. @Netchaiev's answer and those provided in the aforementioned posts are correct for a specific $n$, but what about for an arbitrary integer $n>0$ ?

I guess that the proof-by-induction should do the job but I don't see how.

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate. The previous posts do not prove, at least as far as I understood, that "if the rule is valid for $n>0$ it is also valid for $n+1$", but only that "the rule is valid for $n$".

Comment: @utob iit's strange what you are asking, logiclly speaking let's denote $P(n) : l(n)=r(n)$, then $P(n)$ is true **for any** $n$ as proved in the answer below. hence $p(n+1)$  is also is valid for every $n$, and so is $p(n+2)$ and so on. Now logiclly you can deduce that $anything \implies P(n+1) $ is also valid. Because if something is valid then it can be implied by anything else. (and hence $ P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ is valid)

Comment: @utobi _"What I'd like to do is to prove that (1) (or (2)) holds for **any** integer $n>0$. Netchaiev's answer [...] is correct for a specific $n$, but what about for an arbitrary integer $n>0$ ?"_ . Here I see that you are confused, because **Netchaiev's answer  does prove the result for any specific integer $n>0$ , which means for any integer at all** .  In order to prove something for any $n$ , there are a lot of methods: using direct computation as in the answer below, using induction , using proof by contradiction, .... (and any other logical reasoning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)& = \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{n-r}{n}\right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{n\times \cdots \times (n-k+1)}{n^k} \\
& =  \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k} \\
& = \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k
\end{align*}
$$
and the global equality follows.

Comment: what about "I can't find any reasonable quantity that if added on both sides leads to equality for n+1, i.e. the quantity that completes the proof" ?

Comment: Because each term of the sum will change at the stage $n+1$...

Comment: I've edited the question, hoping it is clearer than the previous one. Please, see below the EDIT section.